# Change the date format in a csv .txt file before importing using mysqlbulkloader

Tags: mysql, vb.net

For anybody looking for an answer in the future, the best way to do this is using the load data local infile option, where you will need to call out your particular columns and designate the columns you want to preprocess with an @ symbol.  like the example below.  You may also need to update both your client and server side settings to allow the load data option to work.

in my code example below i wanted to change the createdate field from the m/d/y format to the mysql format of yyyy-mm-dd

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:/Users/username/Documents/SAP/SAP GUI/QNs.txt'
                                            IGNORE
                                            INTO TABLE tbl_quality_notification
                                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
                                            LINES starting by '|'
                                             TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                                            IGNORE 6 ROWS
                                            
                                            (@CreateDate,
                                            NotificationNumber,
                                            ItemNumber,
                                            WorkOrder,
                                            MaterialNumber,
                                            MaterialDescription,
                                            Disposition,
                                            DeptResponsible,
                                            OperationCaused,
                                            DefQtyInt,
                                            DefQtyExt,
                                            TotalQty,
                                            WcOpFoundAt,
                                            OpDescription,
                                            DefectLocation,
                                            ProblemType,
                                            ProblemDescription,
                                            CauseCode,
                                            CauseDescription,
                                            RootCause,
                                            CorrectiveAction)
                                            SET CreateDate = STR_TO_DATE(@CreateDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: You could use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax instead, which offers features to adress such concern.

Comment: And fyi, a bit picky and no help to the question.  csv files are delimited by commas (Comma Separated Values).  What you've got there looks more like a combo fixed width and | delimited file

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE almost works but somebody has a random " in one of the fields, and i've been trying to use replace(@column,'"','') to address it but it aint working yo.

Comment: can you give the txt file as actual text. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: doneski, thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GMB, load local infile seems to be the right solution.  i will post a new thread to address the invalid character string issues.